# Delphi/Indy multithreading Server

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I am trying to turn my app multithreading. What I want to achieve is:
- Receive command via TidHTTPServer
- Execute local action (might involve using tidHTTP to send/receive data to other services)
- return execution result to the original caller

since I am pretty new to multi-threading I would like to know if my design-idea is correct

1. TMsgHandler=Class(TThread)
2. in TidHTTPServer.OnCommandGet I create a new instance of TMsgHandler and pass ARequestInfo and AResponseInfo
3. TMsgHandler.Excecute interprest the data
4. Can TMsgHandler.Execeute use Objects (descendants of TidHTTP) in my Main to communicate with other services?
5. TMsgHandler sends answer through AResponseInfo and terminates.

will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is not the correct design.

`THTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component. Its `OnCommand...` events are fired in the context of worker threads that Indy creates for you.

As such,  you do not need to derive your `TMsgHandler` from `TThread`.  Do your `TIdHTTP` directly in the context of the `OnCommand...` thread instead.  A response will not be sent back to the client until your event handler exits (unless you send one manually).  However, you should not share a single `TIdHTTP` from the main thread (unless you absolute need to, in which case you would need to synchronize access to it). You should create a new `TIdHTTP` dynamically directly in your `OnCommand...`/`TMsgHandler` code as needed.

Comment: OK, thank you. Since the services I am accessing require OAuth I would like to initialize the connection at the start and the use those authenticated sockets... :-/
I could of course, pass the token into the thread from OnCommand...
Well thank you for the start guidance. I will see where I end up. :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBures you could, at least, pool the `TIdHTTP` objects and hand them out to `OnCommand...` threads as needed, and then put them back in the pool when done. Just make sure the pooling is thread-safe.